# Jquery Accordion slide next header when previous item removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Please find this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/valentynvynogradskyi/yy0a1x54/).

If you click "delete" while item collapsed - then when you unwrap next one, it's header will slide up, like accordions content, anyone have idea why does this happen?

I think it may happen because the accordion somehow starts thinking that h3 now is a content - and on click collapse it, but i can't make it work anyway.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#myClicker').click(function () {
        var head = $(this).closest('h3');
        var content = head.next('div');
        content.add(head).fadeOut(300, function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    $("#accordion").accordion({
        autoHeight: true
    });
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
     <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a><input type="button" id="myClicker" value="delete" /></h3>

    <div>
        <p>Section 1 Content</p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>

    <div>
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>

    <div>
        <p>Section 3 Content</p>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>

    <div>
        <p>Section 4 Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPD 1: 
After some experimenting i end up with:

```
$('#myClicker').click(function(){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var head = $(this).closest('h3');
    var content = head.next('div');

        head.fadeOut(300,function(){
            head.remove();
            content.remove();
        });

});
```

Comment: What you want? Do you want to slide next panel when previous one deleted?

Comment: Have you tried my example?

Comment: Yes. Do you want to remove the `slideup` effect? Can you please explain what you need?

Comment: yes, i want next header not disappear, coz it is not valid behavior in accordion context

Comment: **[How about this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yy0a1x54/5/)**?

Comment: Thatz work, thanks, but what the secret here? Where the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/yy0a1x54/14/).

```
$(function() {
    $('#myClicker').click(function(){
      var head = $(this).closest('h3');
       var content = head.next('div');

     content.add(head).remove();
    });
    $("#accordion").accordion({ autoHeight: true});
    $("#accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true });
});
```

Comment: Yes, but once you add .fadeOut - you'll get the behavior i'm talking about

Comment: Yes, if you do `console.log($(this));` inside the `fadeOut` function then you can see it's looping twice, one for `header` and once for 'panel' so I think removing one by one is creating issue. Not 100% sure about that but to me that's the issue.

Comment: see my update in question, there might be some new idea of why that's happening